# `for<'r, 'r, 'r> ...` cannot be sent between threads safely

Tags: rust, hyper

I learn Rust and I tried to build a micro route system built on top of hyper (it's just for learning purpose, I know frameworks exists).

I don't know how to share a "complex" type with an `hyper::server::Handler`. I read the error message, but unfortunately, I don't understand how to fix it (most of time, the rust compiler just says what to fix, right now I'm not sure to understand).

Here is a (non-)working over-simplified example of what I tried:

```
extern crate hyper;
use std::sync::Mutex;

use hyper::*;

type Route = (method::Method, String, Box<Fn(server::Request, server::Response)>);

struct MyHandler {
    routes: Mutex<Vec<Route>>
}

impl server::Handler for MyHandler {
    fn handle(&self, req: server::Request, mut res: server::Response) {
        // This is not important
    }
}

fn main() {
    // This is not important
}
```

And the error is:

```
error: the trait bound `for<'r, 'r, 'r> std::ops::Fn(hyper::server::Request<'r, 'r>, hyper::server::Response<'r>) + 'static: std::marker::Send` is not satisfied [--explain E0277]
  --> src/main.rs:12:10
   |>
12 |>     impl server::Handler for MyHandler {
   |>          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: `for<'r, 'r, 'r> std::ops::Fn(hyper::server::Request<'r, 'r>, hyper::server::Response<'r>) + 'static` cannot be sent between threads safely
note: required because it appears within the type `Box<for<'r, 'r, 'r> std::ops::Fn(hyper::server::Request<'r, 'r>, hyper::server::Response<'r>) + 'static>`
note: required because it appears within the type `(hyper::method::Method, std::string::String, Box<for<'r, 'r, 'r> std::ops::Fn(hyper::server::Request<'r, 'r>, hyper::server::Response<'r>) + 'static>)`
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::ptr::Unique<(hyper::method::Method, std::string::String, Box<for<'r, 'r, 'r> std::ops::Fn(hyper::server::Request<'r, 'r>, hyper::server::Response<'r>) + 'static>)>`
note: required because it appears within the type `alloc::raw_vec::RawVec<(hyper::method::Method, std::string::String, Box<for<'r, 'r, 'r> std::ops::Fn(hyper::server::Request<'r, 'r>, hyper::server::Response<'r>) + 'static>)>`
note: required because it appears within the type `std::vec::Vec<(hyper::method::Method, std::string::String, Box<for<'r, 'r, 'r> std::ops::Fn(hyper::server::Request<'r, 'r>, hyper::server::Response<'r>) + 'static>)>`
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Mutex<std::vec::Vec<(hyper::method::Method, std::string::String, Box<for<'r, 'r, 'r> std::ops::Fn(hyper::server::Request<'r, 'r>, hyper::server::Response<'r>) + 'static>)>>`
note: required because it appears within the type `MyHandler`
note: required by `hyper::server::Handler`
```

It works if I use a simple integer, but not with the `Route` type.

So, there is a problem with the trait and something about "cannot be sent between threads safely". Reading `hyper` doc, I added a `Mutex`, but I must be dumb, *I have no idea what I am doing*, not sure if I should just stop to learn Rust, or keep trying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're nearly there.

The error is saying that `MyHandler` doesn't implement the `Send` trait, which means that a type can be sent safely to other threads:

```
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Mutex<std::vec::Vec<(hyper::method::Method, std::string::String, Box<for<'r, 'r, 'r> std::ops::Fn(hyper::server::Request<'r, 'r>, hyper::server::Response<'r>) + 'static>)>>`
note: required because it appears within the type `MyHandler`
note: required by `hyper::server::Handler`
```

The error does point to the right place, but it's a bit overwhelming.  The first line is:

```
note: `for<'r, 'r, 'r> std::ops::Fn(hyper::server::Request<'r, 'r>, hyper::server::Response<'r>) + 'static` cannot be sent between threads safely
```

Which is saying that a `Fn` type doesn't implement `Send`.  This is the one in your `Route` type:

```
type Route = (method::Method, String, Box<Fn(server::Request, server::Response)>);
```

A `Fn` closure is only `Send` if all of the variables it captures are also `Send`, but here we don't know whether any closure passed in will be suitable.

The solution is simple: constrain the `Fn` type to be `Send`:

```
type Route = (method::Method, String, Box<Fn(server::Request, server::Response)+Send>);
```